# Show loading icon in SemanticUI Message after button press until API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am making an app that uses an API to create a title and put it in a Semantic UI Message.

As soon as I press the button, I want a loading icon to appear and then disappear once titleText.length > 0. How can I do this?

This is my code without the Icon.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Header, Message, Icon} from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default function Writer() {

    const [titleText, setTitleText] = useState('');

    const getResponse = () => {
        //Does Some Stuff
        }).then((response) => {
            setTitleText(response.data.choices[0].text)
        })

return (
    <div>
        <Button onClick={getResponse}></Button>


        <Message visible={titleText.length > 0} hidden={titleText.length === 0}>
            <Header
                icon textAlign='center'
                content={titleText}
            />
        </Message>
        
    </div>
    )
}
```

This is what I tried to add:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

I added this to the start of the API response function:

```
    const getAPIResponse = () => {
        setLoading(true)
```

I also created another message that should only appear after the first button press, and dissapear after the API response is gathered:

```
                        <Message visible={loading === true} hidden={titleText.length > 0}>
                            <Icon name='circle notched' loading />
                        </Message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this (I don't know Semantic UI) :

```
<Message class={` ${loading ? 'visible' : 'hidden'} `}>
   <Icon name='circle notched' loading />
</Message>
```